# Using tf metrics in multiprocessing

Tags: python, tensorflow, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

So, I am using something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


def parallel_method(*args, **kwargs):
    ... stuff
    queue.put(recall_value)


queue= Queue()
for sample, ground_truth, ecef in zip(x, y, ecef_list):
    p = Process(target=parallel_method,
                args=(x, y, queue))
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()
for process in processes:
    process.join()
recall = 0
while not queue.empty()
    recall += queue.get()
return recall / len(y)
```

However, doint just the average at the end is not precise and I would like to use `tf.keras.metrics.Recall` that has the update directly. Something like this.

```
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Recall

def parallel_method(*args, **kwargs):
    ... stuff
    metric.update_state(y_true, y_pred)


recall = Recall()
for sample, ground_truth, ecef in zip(x, y, ecef_list):
    p = Process(target=parallel_method,
                args=(x, y, recall))
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()
for process in processes:
    process.join()
return recall.result().numpy()
```

This does not work, but is it a way to make it work? It makes sense becase of how TF works that recall is already made for working in parallel so I was thinking it should not be that hard to make it work.

---

I tried adding a metric to the Queue and then using [`merge_state`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Recall#merge_state) at the end instead of the average but then it takes forever to compute for some reason.

I don't even get to usign `merge_state`, it takes forever the parallel loop.